# Как синхронизировать анимацию?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Когда открыто меню и панель с подкатегориями, при закрытии панель с подкатегориями исчезает быстрее.

1. Как синхронизировать анимацию скрытия панелей моб. меню?
2. Из за чего они скрываются с разной скоростью если у всех стоит одинаковый duration?
3. Почему при загрузке страницы происходит анимация?

```js
    $('.trigger-menu').on('click', function() {
      $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
    });
    $('.bg').on('click', function() {
      $("#mobile-menu-trigger:checked,.menu-inner-trigger:checked").prop("checked", false).change();
      $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
    });
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.mobile-menu {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  animation-name: slidemenuback;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: easy-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: 3px 0 4px lightgrey;
  background: #fff;
}
.mobile-menu__header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff4081;
  background: #fff;
}
.mobile-menu__logo-wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mobile-menu__list {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.mobile-menu__item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.mobile-menu__link {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
.mobile-menu__inner {
  background: #f78a8a;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation-name: slidemenuback;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: easy-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#mobile-menu-trigger:checked + .mobile-menu {
  animation-name: slidemenu;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: easy-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

input[data-menu="menu"]:checked + .mobile-menu__inner {
  animation-name: slidemenu;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: easy-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.display-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.trigger-menu {
  background: #91a2f7;
  float: right;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-open .bg {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.menu-back-trigger {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff4081;
}

@keyframes slidemenu {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes slidemenuback {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <label class="trigger-menu" for="mobile-menu-trigger">Trigger</label>
    <input id="mobile-menu-trigger" class="display-hidden" type="checkbox">
    <nav class="mobile-menu">
      <header class="mobile-menu__header">
        <div class="mobile-menu__logo-wrapper">

        </div>
      </header>
      <ul class="mobile-menu__list">
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <label class="mobile-menu__link" for="menu-inner-trigger-1">Category</label>
          <input id="menu-inner-trigger-1" class="menu-inner-trigger display-hidden" type="checkbox" data-menu="menu">
          <div class="mobile-menu__inner">
            <label class="mobile-menu__link menu-back-trigger" for="menu-inner-trigger-1">Category</label>
            <ul class="mobile-menu__inner-list">
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category2
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category3
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category4
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category5
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <label class="mobile-menu__link" for="menu-inner-trigger-2">Category2</label>
          <input id="menu-inner-trigger-2" class="menu-inner-trigger display-hidden" type="checkbox" data-menu="menu">
          <div class="mobile-menu__inner">
            <label class="mobile-menu__link" for="menu-inner-trigger-2">Category2</label>
            <ul class="mobile-menu__inner-list">
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category2
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category3
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category4
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category5
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
            Delivery
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
            About
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Поставь анимациям стиль `animation-timing-function: linear`. А исчезает по-разному потом, что ширина подменю меньше чем самого меню

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Конкретно в данном случае тут не нужна анимация, достаточно `transition`.
   При помощи JS необходимо выключать только чекбокс `#mobile-menu-trigger`, а затем отслеживать `transtionend` для меню и только после этого выключать чекбокс для внутреннего меню, чтобы невидимо скрыть его.

> **Примечание:** поскольку `transtionend` срабатывает на любые `transtion` внутри блока, а нам необходимо определить конец анимации только внешнего меню, необходимо сделать проверку на то, какой именно блок закончил анимацию *(1)*.

2. Рассинхронизация анимаций происходила по причине того, что меню категорий находилось внутри элемента, к которому применяется анимация и, соответственно, ее скорость увеличивалась в два раза. *Пояснение*: когда запускалась анимация, внешнее меню начинало двигаться влево со скоростью 100пкс / 0.3с; одновременно начинало двигаться влево внутреннее меню с такой же скоростью плюс собственная скорость 100пкс / 0.3с, соответственно, его скорость была (100пкс / 0.3с)*2.
3. Потому что изначально меню находится в видимой области, а потом уже начинается анимация и уводит меню за пределы видимой области.

```js
$('.trigger-menu').on('click', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
});

$('.bg').on('click', function() {
  $("#mobile-menu-trigger:checked").prop("checked", false);
  // по клику на .bg выключаем чекбокс, который связан с внешним меню
  
  $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
});

$('.mobile-menu').on('transitionend', function(e) {
  // вешаем обработчик на событие "transitionend" для внешнего меню
  
  if ( $(e.target).attr('class') === 'mobile-menu' ) { // (1)
    // поскольку событие "transitionend", несмотря на то, что навешено только на внешнее меню, срабатывает также при окончании transition у .mobile-menu__inner, нам надо отделить .mobile-menu.
    // e.target позволяет определить элемент, на котором происходит событие transitionend. Затем мы проверяем есть ли у него класс mobile-menu и, если есть, выключаем чекбокс, который связан с внутренним меню, т. о. скрывая его 
    
    $('input[data-menu="menu"]').prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.mobile-menu {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: .5s;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: 3px 0 4px lightgrey;
  background: #fff;
}
.mobile-menu__header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff4081;
  background: #fff;
}
.mobile-menu__logo-wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mobile-menu__list {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.mobile-menu__item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.mobile-menu__link {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
.mobile-menu__inner {
  background: #f78a8a;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: .5s;
}

#mobile-menu-trigger:checked + .mobile-menu,
input[data-menu="menu"]:checked + .mobile-menu__inner {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.display-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.trigger-menu {
  background: #91a2f7;
  float: right;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-open .bg {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.menu-back-trigger {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff4081;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <label class="trigger-menu" for="mobile-menu-trigger">Trigger</label>
    <input id="mobile-menu-trigger" class="display-hidden" type="checkbox">
    <nav class="mobile-menu">
      <header class="mobile-menu__header">
        <div class="mobile-menu__logo-wrapper">

        </div>
      </header>
      <ul class="mobile-menu__list">
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <label class="mobile-menu__link" for="menu-inner-trigger-1">Category</label>
          <input id="menu-inner-trigger-1" class="menu-inner-trigger display-hidden" type="checkbox" data-menu="menu">
          <div class="mobile-menu__inner">
            <label class="mobile-menu__link menu-back-trigger" for="menu-inner-trigger-1">Category</label>
            <ul class="mobile-menu__inner-list">
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category2
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category3
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category4
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category5
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <label class="mobile-menu__link" for="menu-inner-trigger-2">Category2</label>
          <input id="menu-inner-trigger-2" class="menu-inner-trigger display-hidden" type="checkbox" data-menu="menu">
          <div class="mobile-menu__inner">
            <label class="mobile-menu__link" for="menu-inner-trigger-2">Category2</label>
            <ul class="mobile-menu__inner-list">
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category2
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category3
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category4
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category5
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
            Delivery
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
            About
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: animation использовал потому-что на моб. устройствах transition выполнялся с рывками.
Правильно ли я понял, что все ефекты вложеных елемнтов всегда выполняются в 2 раза быстрее?
Пожалуйста, обьясните, что происходит в этой части кода
if ( $(e.target).attr('class') === 'mobile-menu' ) { // (1)
    $('input[data-menu="menu"]').prop("checked", false);
  }
Я понимаю, что он выключать чекбокс, но никак не пойму как он обращается к нужному и не могу обьяснить эту часть $(e.target).attr('class') === 'mobile-menu'

Comment: обновил ответ, добавил комментарии в код и сам текст.

Answer (score 1):

Пробуем так:

```js
$('#Trigger').click( function(){
 $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .trigger {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #d5d5d5;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.container .trigger:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.container .sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.94, 0.32, 0.97) 400ms;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.94, 0.32, 0.97) 400ms;
}
.container .sidebar.active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
}
.container .sidebar .option_menu {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  margin: 2px 4px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div id="Trigger" class="trigger">
  !
 </div>
 <div class="sidebar">
  <div class="option_menu">1</div>
  <div class="option_menu">2</div>
  <div class="option_menu">3</div>
  <div class="option_menu">4</div>
  <div class="option_menu">5</div>
 </div>
</div>
```